# It is possible to change line width for smoother lines in case of diagnostic plot (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to customise diagnostic plots in ggplot2. I have tried this:

```
library(ggfortify)
library(ggplot2)
model1 <- lm(len~dose*supp, data = ToothGrowth)
autoplot(model1, which = 1, label.size = 3, data = ToothGrowth, size=3, colour = "dose",
     smooth.colour = 'darkblue', smooth.linetype="dotted", smooth.linesize=3)
```

I got this picture:

[image]

I changed the line colour and line type for smoother line, but I do not know how can I change the line width. I have tried "smooth.linesize", but it is not working. It is possible somehow change the line width?

Can somebody help me? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add another layer to your plot since `autoplot.lm` does not provide the desired argument `smooth.linesize`. The first part generates your plot, `p`.

```
p <- autoplot(model1, which = 1, label.size = 3, data = ToothGrowth, size=3, colour = "dose",
     smooth.colour = 'darkblue', smooth.linetype="dotted")
```

The desired data of the smoothed line can now be found somewhere deep inside `p` here: `p@plots[[1]]$layers[[2]]$data`

This can be used as the `data` argument in the call to `geom_*`. The following code generates the plot below.

```
p + geom_line(data = p@plots[[1]]$layers[[2]]$data, aes(x = x, y = y), linetype = 3, col = "red", size = 3)
```

[image]

Another option would be to add the not yet existing aesthetics parameter `size` to the respective layer of the plot object yourself. I guess this option is closer to what you want to achieve.

This can be done via

```
p@plots[[1]]$layers[[2]]$aes_params$size <- 3
p
```

[image]

I hope this helps.