# Shaded area under density curve in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have plotted a distribution and I want to shade the area>95 percentile.
However when I try to use the different techniques documented here:[ggplot2 shade area under density curve by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355849/ggplot2-shade-area-under-density-curve-by-group) It does not work as the length of my dataset differ.

```
AGG[,1]=seq(1:1000)
AGG[,2]=rnorm(1000,mean=150,sd=10)
Z<-data.frame(AGG) 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Z,aes(x=Z[,2]))+stat_density(geom="line",colour="lightblue",size=1.1)+xlim(0,350)+ylim(0,0.05)+geom_vline(xintercept=quantile(Z[,2],prob=0.95),colour="red")+geom_text(aes(x=quantile(Z[,2],prob=0.95)),label="VaR 95%",y=0.0225, colour="red")
#I want to add a shaded area right of the VaR in this chart
```

Comment: Is it necessary that you sample random numbers from the distribution using `rnorm`, or would it be sufficient to plot the empirical function with `dnorm`?

Comment: Actually I cannot use dnorm or something similar because my distribution does not follow the usual laws and I used Monte Carlo simulation to estimate it. So let's say that AGG[,2] is any given of random numbers for which I want to plot the density and shade the area above the 95th percentile

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your useful answer. Too bad it is more complex to shade area on GGplot than using the usual plot function in R.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shading a kernel density plot between two points.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494593/shading-a-kernel-density-plot-between-two-points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the function `WVPlots::ShadedDensity`. I will use this function because its arguments are self-explanatory and therefore the plot can be created very easily. On the downside, the customization is a bit tricky. But once you worked your head around a `ggplot` object, you'll see that it is not that mysterious.

```
library(WVPlots)

# create the data
set.seed(1)
V1 = seq(1:1000)
V2 = rnorm(1000, mean = 150, sd = 10)
Z <- data.frame(V1, V2)
```

Now you can create your plot.

```
threshold <- quantile(Z[, 2], prob = 0.95)[[1]]
p <- WVPlots::ShadedDensity(frame = Z, 
                            xvar = "V2",
                            threshold = threshold,
                            title = "Your title",
                            tail = "right")
p
```

[image]

But since you want the colour of the line to be lightblue etc, you need to manipulate the object `p`. In this regard, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153417/it-is-possible-to-change-line-width-for-smoother-lines-in-case-of-diagnostic-plo/48157502#48157502) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209025/change-the-color-of-a-ggplot-geom-a-posteriori-after-having-specified-another-c) question.

The object `p` contains four layers: `geom_line`, `geom_ribbon`,  `geom_vline` and `geom_text`. You'll find them here: `p$layers`.

Now you need to change their aesthetic mappings. For `geom_line` there is only one, the `colour`

```
p$layers[[1]]$aes_params
$colour
[1] "darkgray"
```

If you now want to change the line colour to be lightblue simply overwrite the existing colour like so

```
p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$colour <- "lightblue"
```

Once you figured how to do that for one `layer`, the rest is easy.

```
p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$fill <- "grey"     #geom_ribbon
p$layers[[3]]$aes_params$colour <- "red"    #geom_vline
p$layers[[4]]$aes_params$label <- "VaR 95%" #geom_text

p
```

And the plot now looks like this

[image]

Comment: Very elegant and easy to implement solution!

Answer (score 11):

This is a case where ggplot's helper functions and built-in summaries can end up being more troublesome than helpful. In your situation, it's probably best to calculate your summary statistics directly, and then plot those. In the example below, I use `density` and `quantile` from the base `stats` library to compute what will be plotted. Feeding this to ggplot directly ends up being much simpler than trying to manipulate ggplot's summary functions. This way, shading is accomplished using `geom_ribbon` and ggplot's intended aesthetic system; no need to go digging through the plot object.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

y <- rnorm(1000, 150, 10)

cutoff <- quantile(y, probs = 0.95)

hist.y <- density(y, from = 100, to = 200) %$% 
  data.frame(x = x, y = y) %>% 
  mutate(area = x >= cutoff)

the.plot <- ggplot(data = hist.y, aes(x = x, ymin = 0, ymax = y, fill = area)) +
  geom_ribbon() +
  geom_line(aes(y = y)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = cutoff, color = 'red') +
  annotate(geom = 'text', x = cutoff, y = 0.025, color = 'red', label = 'VaR 95%', hjust = -0.1)
print(the.plot)
```

[image]