# Finding AUC for histogram

Tags: r, auc

I have a vector of continuous values say 1000 heights with
`heights <- rnorm(1000, mean = 170, sd = 10)`
which I can plot into a histogram. But I was wondering is there any package or function that allows an approximation of the histogram into a smooth distribution curve and then find the cutoff height where the area under curve would be equal to 0.8?

Comment: This looks like a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212824/shaded-area-under-density-curve-in-ggplot2

Comment: I was wondering if AUC = 0.8 is equal to finding the 20th percentile of my data?

Comment: Also the answer in that post doesn't offer the cutoff value which I need more than the graphical representation of the cutoff?